# when i am trying to select a value in the dropdownitem it wont change instantly i have to exit the dialog box then it does change

Tags: flutter

when i am trying to select a value in the dropdownitem it wont change instantly i have to exit the dialog box then it does change

```
DropdownButton<String>(
    value: _event,
    hint: Text('Course Name'),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    isExpanded: true,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
        _event = newValue;
        _eventid.text = _event!;
      });
    },
    items: dropdownlist.map((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _event = value;
            _eventid.text = _event!;
          });
        },
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To update the value instantly, use statefulbuilder and set statesetter in statefulbuilder.

```
StatefulBuilder(
   builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter refreshState) {
       return ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                'Next',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                refreshState(() {
                  _event = newValue;
                  _eventid.text = _event!;
                });
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: buttonRed,
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 14),
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7), // <-- Radius
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
```

Comment: iam using a dropdown menu inside a dialog how can i use statefulbuilder?

Comment: Wrap dropdown button with StatefulBuilder.